# How do I call the backend MarkLogic API from my own API in MarkLogic Grove?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

This question is a continuation of the question below.

[How do I handle the REST API in node.js in Marklogic Grove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747392/how-do-i-handle-the-rest-api-in-node-js-in-marklogic-grove)

I was able to implement a sample REST API that can be called when authenticated with Grove, as shown below.

middle-tier/routes/index.js

```
const authProvider = require('../../grove-node-server-utils/auth-helper');

router.get('/my-rest-api/bar',(req, res) => {
  const response = {status : "success"};
  authProvider.isAuthenticated(req,res,()=>{
    res.send(response);
  });
});
```

Next, I want to call the MarkLogic API from within the my-rest-api. I wrote the following through trial and error, but an error occurs.How should I write it?

middle-tier/routes/index.js

```
const authProvider = require('../../grove-node-server-utils/auth-helper');
const backend = require('../../grove-node-server-utils/backend');

router.get('/my-rest-api/bar',(req, res) => {
  const myResponse = {status : "success!!"};
  console.log("start");
  const backendOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/v1/resources/myMarkLogicAPI?p1=test'
  };

  authProvider.isAuthenticated(req,res,()=>{
    console.log("preprocessing");
    backend.call(req, backendOptions, () => {
      console.log("postprocessing")
      res.send(myResponse);
    });
  });
});
```

The error message is: {"message":"TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"}

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the code is expecting a headers property as part of backendOptions. We typically wrap the backend call in a authProvider.getAuth call that returns an authentication header that we pass through to the backend call. You may want to do the same to be sure you are allowed to access the backend.

That said, it may be simpler to use our new [DefaultRestRoute](https://github.com/marklogic-community/grove-node/blob/development/grove-default-routes/rest.js) as mentioned in your previous question. I showed some sample code in there as well.

HTH!

Comment: I have successfully called the MarkLogic API using authProvider.getAuth. Thank you!

My final goal this time is to add processing on the Grove before and after the MarkLogic API call. Is that possible with DefaultRestRoute?